# "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple" - the code works in one case but not in another?

Tags: python, numpy

The following code executes smoothly:

```py
for i in range (1, 10):
    for j in range (1, 10):
        if a1[i][j] == 100:
            if np.count_nonzero(a1[i-1:i+2,j-1:j+2]) > 8:
                a1[i][j] = 1
```

While the following gives the mentioned error:

```py
for i, item in enumerate(myarray):
    for j, element in enumerate(item):  
        if na2[i][j] == 1:
            if numpy.count_nonzero(na2[i-1:i+2,j-1:j+2]) > 2: 
                na3[i][j] = 0
```

I am not able to understand the reason.

Comment: This is a pure Python question, without a GIS component. As such, is is probably better asked in [so].